# Como somar apenas os valores de fisioterapia na list [(8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (28, 50, 110.0, 'Psicologia')]

Tags: python-3.x

Como somar apenas os dados de fisiterapia da seguinte list em pyhton, sendo que fisioterapia é o índice 3 e o valor está no índice 2

```
[(8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (28, 50, 110.0, 'Psicologia')]
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Já que você está trabalhando com uma lista de tuplas e tem os índices fixos (nome do curso e valor a ser somado) basta percorrer a lista através de um `for` e adicionar o valor a uma nova variável sempre que o nome do curso bater com o esperado.

O código abaixo está fazendo isso:

```
ls = [(8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (8, 49, 110.0, 'Fisioterapia'), (28, 50, 110.0, 'Psicologia')]
soma = 0

for x in ls:
    if x[3] == 'Fisioterapia':
        soma += x[2]
```

Comment: Show Evilmaax, vou tentar aqui, obrigado pela ajuda, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui.

Comment: @FlávioPacheco Não esqueça de dar um upvote na resposta e aceitar ela como correta. Assim ajuda outras pessoas tbm